# How do I change the background color of a toggle button when the state changes to true?

Tags: reactjs, togglebutton

I'm still learning the fundamentals of web development and I am stuck. I've created a toggle button in react.js but I can't seem to change the background color when the state changes to true.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```css
.ToggleSwitch {
  background: #e3e8eb;
  border: 3px solid #e3e8eb;
  height: 2em;
  width: 4em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.ToggleSwitch .knob {
  position: relative;
  width: 1.9em;
  height: 1.9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0em;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.ToggleSwitch .knob.active {
  left: 2em;
  background-color: #f37c22;
  border: 1px solid #f37c22;
}
```

```html
import React from "react";
import "./toggleButton.css";

class ToggleButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick} className="ToggleSwitch active" >
        <div className={this.state.isToggleOn ? "knob active" : "knob"} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  doSearch(props) {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = "";
    const submitForm = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      props.getRecipes(searchInput);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass in a variable to class name using template literals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean the background of the whole component? Exactly the same way you do it for the knob.